# How to get related products in product tabs in opencart

Tags: opencart

I created a extra tab and custom design for related products in products page.   I want to get product name,price and to add to cart,image in a loop.   In related product tab check this url I am working on that http://efurnish.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&path=86&product_id=58

```
 <div class="product-related box">
        <div class="box-heading"><span><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</span></div>
        <div class="box-content products-block">
            <?php foreach ($pr

    oducts as $i => $product) { $i=$i+1; ?>
            <?php if( $i%$cols == 1 && $cols > 1 ) { ?>
            <div class="row product-related row-product">
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="col-lg-<?php echo $span;?>">
                    <div class="product-block">
                        <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
                        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>"
                                                                                          title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"
                                                                                          alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
                        <div class="group-item">
                            <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
                            <div class="rating"><img
                                        src="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png"
                                        alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>"/></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div class="price-cart">
                                <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
                                <div class="price">
                                    <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                                    <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                    <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span
                                            class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <div class="cart">
                                    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>"
                                           onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="wishlist"><a class="icon-heart" onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>"><span><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a></span></span>
                        <span class="compare"><a class="icon-retweet" onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>"><span><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php if( $cols > 1 && ($i%$cols == 0 || $i==count($products)) ) { ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

I am using this design http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/store-product-layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option for related products in the product form in the admin panel. You can add related product there to show in the product tab.

Answer (score 0):

To Add Related Products to a product:

1. In OpenCart admin panel navigate to Catalog -> Products
2. Search for the product you would like to add related products. Click
   Edit link to edit it.
3. Choose **Link tab** and scroll down until you see the **"Related Products"** field.
4. Start typing a product name in that field and OpenCart will drop
   down a list of products that start with whatever letters you have
   typed in.
5. Click on the product you want to add as a related product. You will
   see it added to the box below.
6. Repeat step 4-5 for others product you want to add.
7. Click on **save** button

Related products will be added to your product page.